# Docker Port fowarding is not working anymore

Tags: docker, networking, connection, localhost

I have mutiple Docker containers that I use on my machine for testing, etc.,all through port fowarding.

Strangely, for the last four days I have not been able to connect to any of them. I made some tests with application outside of containers, it appears I can still connect to them.

But for every application inside a container I get a "connection reset by peer error"
I might have messed up with dangling docker network interface before this happenned,
but this is my first time having that consequence and now my work is really impeded.

Does anybody know what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the iptables. I don't know which one, but after deleting them and reinstalling everything it started working again.